# wkhtmltopdf not working upon dockerizing my django app

Tags: django, docker, wkhtmltopdf

I was working with my django app on my localserver and There was a view that shows me pdf using wkhtmltopdf, when I decided to dockerize my app this result is shown to me when I try to reach the pdf:
[image]

In views.py:

```
wkhtml_to_pdf = os.path.join(
    settings.BASE_DIR, "wkhtmltopdf.exe")


def resume_pdf(request,id):
    # return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
    options = {
        'page-size': 'A4',
        'page-height': "13in",
        'page-width': "10in",
        'margin-top': '0in',
        'margin-right': '0in',
        'margin-bottom': '0in',
        'margin-left': '0in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'no-outline': None
    }

    template_path = 'frontend/thepdf.html'
    template = get_template(template_path)
    
    context = {"name": "Areeba Seher"}
    html = template.render(context)

    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkhtml_to_pdf)

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)

    # Generate download
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="resume.pdf"'
    theEntry = entry.objects.get(id= id)
    context = {'entry' : theEntry, 'entrybody': markdown(theEntry.body) }
    # print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    # return response
    return PDFTemplateResponse(request=request, cmd_options={'disable-javascript':True}, template=template, context=context)
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.5
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install tesseract-ocr
RUN pip install --upgrade pip    
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

So how can I make wkhtmltopdf work on dockerized django app?